# Problema con metodo Mockito.doAnswer con test unitario

Tags: java, json, spring, mockito

Estoy teniendo un inconveniente me esta danto null una linea y no estoy entiendo por que en base a los test unitarios ,esta son las clases la que yo quiero testear con mockito

```
@Override
    public MerchantReponseModel findMerchanById(Integer idProcessMerchant) throws TransactionException {

        Map<String, Object> params = toMuleRequest(idProcessMerchant);

        samService.execute(MULE_MERCHANT_SERVICE,params,samService.getSamConfig().getUser());

        return toMerchantResponseModel(params);
    }

MerchantReponseModel toMerchantResponseModel(Map<String, Object> params) {
    log.info("Params: {}", params);
    log.info("Params: {}", params.get("respuesta"));

    MerchantReponseModel response = FNJsonUtils.jsonToSerializable(FNJsonUtils.objectToJson(params.get("respuesta")), MerchantReponseModel.class);

    if(response == null){
        throw new ApiSamException(String.valueOf(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()), errorMessageConfig.getHttp500ErrorCode().getOrDefault("ErrorParseMule", "ErrorParseMule"));
    }
    return response;
}

private Map<String, Object> toMuleRequest(Integer idProcessMerchant) {
    MerchantRequestModel merchantModel = MerchantRequestModel.builder()
            .numeroTramiteComercio(idProcessMerchant)
            .accion(HostMerchanActionTypeEnum.GET.getDescription())
            .build();

    return MapMapperUtils.objectToMap(merchantModel);
}
```

Y aca les muestro los test unitario que estaba armando

```
 @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class MerchantProcessDaoImplTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private MerchantProcessDaoImpl merchantProcessDaoImpl;
    @Mock
    private ErrorMessageConfig errorMessageConfigMock;
    
@Mock
private AbstractSamService  samService ;

@Captor
protected ArgumentCaptor<Map<String, Object>> parametersCaptor;

private static String USER;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    USER= "testUser";

}

protected void insertValuesOnMapCaptor (InvocationOnMock invocation, Map<String, Object> newValues) {
    Map<String, Object> capturedParameters = invocation.getArgument(0);
    capturedParameters.putAll(parametersCaptor.getValue());
    capturedParameters.putAll(newValues);
}
@Test
    public void testFindMerchantByI() throws TransactionException {
        Map<String, Object> mockResponseParams = new HashMap<>();
    SamConfig samconfig = new SamConfig();
    samconfig.setUser(USER);
    MerchantReponseModel merchantResponseModel = MerchantReponseModel.builder()
            .numeroTramiteComercio("12")
            .accion("C")
            .build();
mockResponseParams.put("respuesta", merchantResponseModel);
when(samService.getSamConfig()).thenReturn(samconfig);
    Mockito.doAnswer(invocation -> {
        insertValuesOnMapCaptor(invocation, mockResponseParams);
        return null; // Método void, no se necesita retornar ningún valor
    }).when(samService).execute(any(), any(), eq("request"));



    MerchantReponseModel result = merchantProcessDaoImpl.findMerchanById(12);



}
```

Estoy tiendo un inconveniente en la linea

```
MerchantReponseModel response = FNJsonUtils.jsonToSerializable(FNJsonUtils.objectToJson(params.get("respuesta")), MerchantReponseModel.class);
```

Ese response me trae null como que no esta mappeando bien el JSON

```
public static String objectToJson(Object obj) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    
    try {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    }
    catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        logger.error(FN_JSONERROR + obj.toString(), e);
        return null;
    }
}
public static <T> T jsonToSerializable(String json, Class<T> clase){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
    try {
        return (T) mapper.readValue(json, clase);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(FN_JSONERROR + json, e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

ambas clases donde usa el JSON y lo mappea .Pero el tema es que me lo mappea mal en json y por eso rompe y me tira la exception ApiSamException . Mi duda si esta bien el answer escrito o estructura o es algun problema de la implementacion de mockito